# Error en ASM al compilar en 64 Bits en DELPHI

Tags: delphi, delphi-rio, asm

Estoy tratando de convertir una aplicación de Delphi XE3 32 bits a Delphi RIO 64 bits y me da un error en esta parte del codigo.

```
  asm                //El error salta aquí mismo.
     mov eax,0     
     db $0F,$A2       
     mov _ebx,ebx
     mov _ecx,ecx
     mov _edx,edx
  end;
```

El error que me salta es el sgte.
[dcc64 Error] UCMDBDescoberta.pas(90): E1025 Unsupported language feature: 'ASM'.

No tengo nada de experiencia con ASM, cualquier ayuda se agradece.

Comment: No te va a hacer falta la experiencia; dice, literalmente: `La funcionalidad ASM no está soportada`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Siguiendo [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30716643/delphi-xe2-error-compiling-asm-code-with-x64-compiler-unsupported-language-feat) dicen que [la documentación dice](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Converting_32-bit_Delphi_Applications_to_64-bit_Windows#Inline_Assembly_code) que eso no está soportado

> Mixing of assembly statements with Pascal code is not supported in 64-bit applications. Replace assembly statements with either Pascal code or functions written completely in assembly.

Puedes usar pascal puro o alguna otra aproximación que no termine en que se trunquen apuntadores de 64bit en un exit code del hilo que es un DWORD de 32 bit